# Export report in xls format using php doesn't show grid lines

Tags: php, excel

I have a report to be exported in xls format. The report was exported successfully in xls format but gridlines never show up even I have adjusted some options in the ms excel by checking the view gridline checkbox but gridlines still show nothing. I have suspected if maybe there is something wrong with my php export code. can you please help me with this? Here is my code.

xls export code

```
<?php 
 $file="report.xls"; 
 $export ='<center><h1 class="lead">CITY Chamber</h1><img src= "base_url(images/agri_logo.jpg)"  width="130px" height="130px"></center>
<div id="page-wrapper">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter">
<tr>
<td>First Name: </td>
<td>'.$report_rows[0]->fname.'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name: </td>
<td>'. $report_rows[0]->lname.'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender: </td>
<td>'.$report_rows[0]->gender.'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Number: </td>
<td>'.$report_rows[0]->contact.'</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter">

<div class="table-responsive">
             <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><strong>Key Result Areas (KRA) / Program / Projects / Activities</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Target</strong></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><center> '.$report_rows[0]->prev_month_year.'</center></td>
                    <td colspan="2" ><center> '.$report_rows[0]->pres_month_year.' </center></td>
                    <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <form id="at_report_form" method="post">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                    <td> '.$dropdown_brgy1[$data_reports['prev_brgy1']].' </td>
                    <td> '.$dropdown_brgy1[$data_reports['prev_brgy2']].' </td>
                    <td> '.$dropdown_brgy1[$data_reports['pres_brgy1']].' </td>
                    <td> '.$dropdown_brgy1[$data_reports['pres_brgy2']].' </td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>1. KRA No. 1: Production Enhancement & Environment </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> Protection  Agenda (PEEPA)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1.1 Support to Crop Production Enhancement </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1.1.1 Rice Production Self Sufficiency Program</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="margin-left:30px;">a. Provision of  certified seeds</span></td>
                    <td>no. of bags</td>
                    <td>per AT</td>
                    <td><center> '.$data_reports['a'].'</center></td>
                    <td> <center>'.$data_reports['b'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center> '.$data_reports['c'].'</center></td>
                    <td> <center>'.$data_reports['d'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center> '.$data_reports['total_1'].'</center></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>no. of farmers</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['e'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['f'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['g'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['h'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['total_2'].'</center></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;">Rehab Seeds</td>
                    <td>no. of bags</td>
                    <td>per AT</td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['i'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['j'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['k'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['l'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['total_3'].'</center></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>no. of farmers</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['m'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['n'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['o'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['p'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['total_4'].'</center></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="margin-left:30px;">b. Provision of pest control assistance</span></td>
                    <td>no. of kgs (ratoxin)</td>
                    <td>per AT</td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['q'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['r'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['s'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['t'].'</center></td>
                    <td><center>'.$data_reports['total_5'].'</center></td>
                  </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </form>
               </table></div></div>';

              header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
              header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
              echo $export; ?>
```

Output (Gridlines never show up even I have checked the gridlines view checkbox):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

optput ur html using table tags 
use

```
    <table border=1>
```